# Show that $\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} k\log k\leq \frac12n^2\log n-\frac18n^2$ by splitting the summation into two parts.

Tags: summation, logarithms, recursion, upper-lower-bounds

**Question**

> Show that $$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} k\log k\leq \frac12n^2\log n-\frac18n^2$$ *Hint:* Split the summation into two parts, one for $k=2,3,\dots,\lceil n/2\rceil-1,$ and one for $k=\lceil n/2\rceil,\dots,n-1.$

**Solution**

> [image]

Can someone solve the question using the *Hint* mentioned in Question?
I tried but couldn't do anything, one difficult summation becomes two difficult one and I can't do.

Comment: That’s not “simplification,” it is an upper bound.

Comment: Many thanks @Thomas Andrews!!!! Yes, you're right. Could you please explain how we reach that upper bound using the hint?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried following the hint, and if so, what did you find? Following the hint, I got an upper bound of: $$\frac{n^2}{2}\log n-\log 2\frac{n^2}{8},$$ which is weaker than we want, unless $\log$ is base $2.$

Comment: I tried but couldn't do anythig, one difficult summation becomes two difficult one and I can't do

Comment: Well, usually, after doing these splits, you do the dumbest thing you can do. The dumbest thing you could do here, without splittting, is to note $\log(k)\leq \log(n)$ for $k=2,\cdot,n-1$ so you get an upper bound: $$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}k\log(n)=\frac{(n+1)(n-2)}2\log n$$ That’s not good enough, but it is most of the way there. It’s really a very blunt upper bound, which was why I objected to the “simplify” term in your title.

Comment: Many, many thanks dear @Thomas Andrews!!! You are GREAT.

Comment: Never mind, went back and saw the original image Gersion was also lg, so my answer is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any $m$ with $2<m\leq n-1,$

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=2}^{n}k\log_2 k&=\sum_{k=2}^{m-1} k\log k+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1} k\log_2 k\\
&\leq\sum_{k=2}^{m-1}k\log_2(m-1)+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}k\log_2 (n-1)\\
&=\frac{(m+1)(m-2)}{2} \log_2 (m-1)\\&\quad+\frac{(m+n-1)(n-m)}{2}\log_2 (n-1)
\end{align}$$

Now you need to know that

$$\log_2(m-1)\leq \log_2(n/2)=\log_2(n)-1.$$

Finally, when $m=\lceil n/2\rceil,$ then show:

$$\frac{(m+1)(m-2)}{2}\leq \frac{n^2}{8}\\
\frac{(n+m-1)(n-m)}2\leq \frac{3n^2}{8}.$$

So I get:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}k\log_2 k\leq \frac{n^2}{4}\log_2 n-\frac{n^2}8.$$

Comment: That's GREAT. Thank you so, so, sooooo much dear @Thomas Andrews!!! You are very, very nice I should thank you thousand times.